# How do I make Flutter firebase Timestamp to show only date

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Please help me with this. After getting the timestamp from firebase, what it is displaying is this format  `2019-04-16 12:18:06.018950`
I am getting this as a stream from my firebase but I want it to be in this format `2019-04-16` just the date and not time.

Comment: This is my code:

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can achieve this using the [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

```
String timeString = '2019-04-16 12:18:06.018950';
DateTime date = DateTime.parse(timeString);
print(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(date)); // prints 2019-04-16
```

make sure to add the `intl` package to the dependencies in your `pubspec`

```
intl: ^0.16.1
```

and also import it into your dart file

```
 import 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart';
```

**OR**

2. you can use the `split` method on the time string

```
String timeString = '2019-04-16 12:18:06.018950';
print(timeString.split(" ")[0]); // prints 2019-04-16
```

Comment: I am already using the split method. the issue is that I want just the date to be display when i get the timestamp from firebase.                                                                                                                  Text(
                              snapshots.data.documents[0]['Fecha']
                                  .toDate()
                                  .toString(),
                              style: GoogleFonts.monda(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
                            ),

Comment: Do this then Text( snapshots.data.documents[0]['Fecha'] .toDate() .toString().split(" ")[0], style: GoogleFonts.monda( textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)), ),

Comment: What is the not browser way of doing this? I need to do this on android device.

Comment: @Stayheuh `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`